# Random variables $X,Y,Z$ with $\Bbb P(X>Y),\Bbb P(Y>Z),\Bbb P(Z>X)>\frac12$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Is it possible to find random variables $X,Y,Z$ for which simultaneously $\Bbb P(X>Y),\Bbb P(Y>Z),\Bbb P(Z>X)>\frac12$?

This is the complete statement of the problem. I tried drawing pictures to see if it is possible, and obviously, the answer should be impossible. But I don't know exactly how to show it mathematically.

Comment: [Non-transitive dice](https://www.google.com/search?q=non-transitive+dice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to 'show it mathematically' that it is impossible, because it is in fact possible to find random variables that satisfy the conditions given.

---

Edited to respond to comment:

For example

$X\sim{\rm Uniform}(\{1,6,8\})$;

$Y\sim{\rm Uniform}(\{3, 5, 7\})$

$Z\sim{\rm Uniform}(\{2, 4, 9\})$

Comment: For example?${}{}{}$

Comment: @quasi: I have edited my answer to include an example.